# serializing and submitting a form with jQuery POST and php isn't working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm trying to send a form's data using jQuery. However, data does not reach the server and it keeps using the `GET` function to get ./?page=game&mode=search&type=private and it keeps getting that page and doesn't stop getting it. Can you please tell me what i'm doing wrong?

Php:

```
if (isset($_GET['type'])) {
    $type = $secure->clean($_GET['type']);
} else {
    $type = '';
}

    if ($type == 'private') { 

         if ( isset($_POST['submit']))   {
             $name = $secure->clean($_REQUEST['name']);
             $checkuser = $db->fetch("SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE name == '$name''");
             if ($checkuser) {
                 $data ='<h1> The user you searched for does not exist. </h1>
            <a class="goback message" href="#">Continue</a>';

             } 
         } else {

            $checkMatch = $db->query("SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE `id` = '".$account['id']."'");
            while ($info = mysql_fetch_array($checkMatch)) {
                $status = $info['status'];
                $gameid = $info['gameid'];
            }

            if($status = 'NULL') {

            $data ='<h1> Who do you want to battle against? </h1><br />
                    <form action=""  method="post" id="form-pb" name="pb"   target="_self" >
                    USERNAME:<input name="name" type="text" size="40" maxlength="40" />

                    <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Search"/>
                    </form>
                    <a class="goback" href="#">Cancel</a>';
            } 

        }

    echo $data;
    exit;   

    }
```

Javascripit

```
case 'submit':
        $.post('./?page=game&mode=search&type=private', $("#form-pb").serialize(), function(data){
            var $response=$(data);
            var error = $response.filter('h3').text();
            $('.search').html(data);                
            if(!error){
                match = setInterval(function(){
                if(!$('.search').length){
                    $('#main_container').prepend('<div id="popup"><div class="opacity"></div><div class="search"></div></div>');
                }
                $('.search').load('./?page=game&mode=search&type=private', function(){
                    var meta = $('#stopMe').attr('content');                                var meta = $('#stopMe').attr('content');
                    if(meta){
                        meta = meta.split("URL="), meta = meta[1];
                        window.location = meta;                                         
                    }                           
                });                             
                },1000);                    
            }
        });         
    break;
```

And the form is

```
<form action=""  method="post" id="form-pb" name="pb"   target="_self" >
                USERNAME:<input name="name" type="text" size="40" maxlength="40" />

                <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Search"/>
                </form>
```

Comment: What does $("#form-pb").serialize() output?

Comment: Have you tried capturing the request (for example in Chrome Right Click anywhere -> Inspect Element -> Network and then execute the $.post())?

Comment: Yes, here is the screen shot : http://prntscr.com/1zpsbd  , It just keeps send the request, but POST once and it keeps sending GET

Comment: Well, that's what's written in your script: $.post is being once and then you call $.load (GET request) every 1 second via setInterval.

Comment: But it doesn't execute my php code?

Comment: Your PHP code is being executed. Have a look at the requests made in the network box from Chrome, for each request your code has been executed. You can look at the results by clicking on the queries.

Comment: When I type in a username that isn't in the database, it's supposed to echo `$data ='<h1> The user you searched for does not exist. </h1>
     <a class="goback message" href="#">Continue</a>';` but it doesn't, whats wrong?

Comment: This block: if( isset($_POST['submit'])) gets only executed when you post something.

Comment: I thought I was posting something, so how do I execute it without posting something?

Comment: I got you wrong. I'm going to write an answer what's wrong because I can't use code highlighting in here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to fix this:

```
$checkuser = $db->fetch("SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE name == '$name''");
```

to something like that:

```
$checkuser_res=$db->query("SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE name == '$name''");
if($checkuser_res->num_rows==1)
{
 // The user exists
}
else
{
 // The user doesn't exist
}
```

For this I'm assuming you are using mysqli, if it is a special mysql wrapper, it could be possible that your code also works.